# retrieving certain attributes using DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to figure out how parse an html page to get a forms action value, the labels within the form tab as well as the input field names. I took at look at [php.net Domdocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and it tells me to get a childnode but all that does is give me errors that it doesnt exist. I also tried doing print_r of the variable holding the html content and all that shows me is length=1. Can someone show me a few samples that i can use because php.net is confusing to follow.

```
<?php

$content = "some-html-source";
$content = preg_replace("/&(?!(?:apos|quot|[gl]t|amp);|#)/", '&amp;', $content);

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$form = $dom->getElementsByTagName('form');

print_r($form);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `DomXPath` instead of `getElementsByTagName` because it allows you to select attribute values directly and returns a `DOMNodeList` object just like `getElementsByTagName`. The `@` in `@action` indicates that we're selecting by attribute.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($content);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$action = $xpath->query('//form/@action')->item(0);
var_dump($action);
```

Similarly, to get the first `input`

```
$action = $xpath->query('//form/input')->item(0);
```

To get all `input` fields

```
for($i=0;$i<$xpath->query('//form/input')->length;$i++) {
    $label = $xpath->query('//form/input')->item($i);
    var_dump($label);       
}
```

If you're not familiar with XPath, I recommend viewing [these examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: thanks , i was just looking into domxpath() , what does the // do in the query?

Comment: // searches the entire document

Comment: got it thanks, one mroe question if you dont mind. The xpath path using firebug on the form that i'm using looks like this, /html/body/div/div/form/div[2]/input . how do i reference the div[#] in the query?

Comment: You can use `form//input` to get all descendant inputs instead of just direct children

Comment: does it matter that the inputs are nested heavily in divs? or will work as form//input regardless of how deep the dom goes to get to the input

Comment: i got it to work thanks :)  i did //form//input . i guess it doesnt matter what the dom layout is